# Dlookup returns null when data exists

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi I have been trying this for hours and it doesn't matter how much I search to try different options I cannot get the lookup for give a result that I am looking for. I am testing it using a date and work code that I know is in the table that I am referring to.

I am using the input box to provide the date and fixing the work code as 13 (Dispatch). The lookup should be returning the date in the table as the date input is in the table. My code is:

```
Sub Append_Dispatch()

Dim dbs As Object
Dim qdf As querydef
Dim InputDateString As String
Dim InputDate As Date
Dim RtnDate As String
Dim chkDate As Date
Dim WC As Long

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set qdf = dbs.querydefs("Dispatch Append to Production Data")
WC = 13

InputDateString = InputBox("Please enter start date to import", "Date")
InputDate = DateValue(InputDateString)


RtnDate = DLookup("[Date of Action]", "Production Data", "[Date of Action]= #" & InputDate & "# AND [Work Code] =  " & WC & "")
chkDate = DateValue(RtnDate)
 If InputDate = chkDate Then
    IB = MsgBox("This dispatch date has already been entered:" & vbCrLf & "Please check and use a date after " & Dte, vbOKOnly, "Date Error")
    Exit Sub

End If
 'qdf.Parameters("Dispatch Date").Value = InputDate
    'qdf.Execute
    'qdf.Close
    'Set qdf = Nothing
    'Set dbs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also I cannot get the code to work after the end if to input the parameter and run the append query. But that is another issue.

Any ideas please.....

Comment: What data type is Work Code?

Comment: also what does `debug.? "[Date of Action]", "Production Data", "[Date of Action]= #" & InputDate & "# AND [Work Code] =  " & WC & "")` show?

Comment: At a guess, this is an issue with date.

Comment: Debug states: Run-time error '94', Invalid use of Null.
Work Code is a number in the table.

Comment: I did this:
  Debug.Print "[Date of Action]", "Production Data", "[Date of Action]= #" &   InputDate & "# AND [Work Code] =  " & WC & ""; show

It bought up this [Date of Action]            Production Data             [Date of Action]= #09/02/2017# AND [Work Code] =  13

Comment: Fionnuala, what would be the date issue? The table is a date and I have made sure that the input is also a date.

Comment: Check that your query date format is year, month, day to ensure compatibility.

Comment: the date is in dd/mm/yyyy format, why do I have to change it around?

Comment: Because a date is a number, that is only a format. In VBA it is always better to use year, month, day.